# Replace a dictionary value in a list of dictionaries with a value from another list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary, python-requests

I have been struggling with this problem:

I have two lists of dictionaries:

```
list_dic1 =  [{'id': '2baf70d1-42bb-4437-b551-e5fed5a87abe', 'title': 'Castle in the Sky',  'director': 'Hayao Miyazaki', 'producer': 'Isao Takahata', 'people': ['https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/']},....]

list_dic2 = [{'name': 'Pazu', 'movies': ['Castle in the Sky']}....]
```

I want to replace the value of `list_dic1['people']` (a list) with a list of `list_dic2['name']`
if  `list_dic1['title'] in list_dic2['movies']`

in the end, I want to have something like this:

```
list_dict3 = [{'id': '2baf70d1-42bb-4437-b551-e5fed5a87abe', 'title': 'Castle in the Sky',  'director': 'Hayao Miyazaki', 'producer': 'Isao Takahata', 'people': ['person1', 'person2'....]},....]
```

Here is the code I've written so far:

```
def make_get_request(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.json()


def get_movies():
    data = make_get_request("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films")
    movies_list = []
    pe = get_people_in_movies()
    print(data)
    print(pe)

    for dat in data:
        for t in pe:

            if dat['title'] in t['movies']:
                dat["people"] = copy.deepcopy(t["name"])
                movies_list.append(dat)

    print(movies_list)
    return jsonify(movies_list)



def get_people_in_movies():
    people_movies = make_get_request("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people")
    people_and_movies_list = []
    for pe in people_movies:
        people_movies_dict = {'name': pe['name'], 'movies': [make_get_request(i)['title'] for i in pe['films']]}



    return people_and_movies_list
```

Last question:

Accessing the API is a time-intensive operation, I don't want it to happen on every page load. so I want to make sure that the information on the page is not older than 1 minute when the page is loaded.

Comment: to clarify, is list_dic1 the "data" returned by one of those queries, and list_dic2 the "data" returned by the other?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

First question:

```
def replace_people(lst1, lst2):
    for dict1 in lst1:
        backup = dict1['people']
        dict1['people'] = []
        for dict2 in lst2:
            if dict1['title'] in dict2['movies']:
                dict1['people'].append(dict2['name'])
        if len(dict1['people']) == 0:
            dict1['people'] = backup
```

usage example:

```
list_dic1 = [{'id': '2baf70d1-42bb-4437-b551-e5fed5a87abe', 'title': 'Castle in the Sky',  'director': 'Hayao Miyazaki', 'producer': 'Isao Takahata', 'people': ['https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/']},{'id': 'ffffffff-42bb-4437-b551-ffffffffffff', 'title': 'Amaterasu',  'director': 'Hayao Miyazaki', 'producer': 'Isao Takahata', 'people': ['https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/']}]
list_dic2 = [{'name': 'Pazu', 'movies': ['Castle in the Sky']},{'name': 'Dola', 'movies': ['Castle in the Sky','Amaterasu']}]

print("1 -", [{dict1['title']:dict1['people']} for dict1 in list_dic1])
replace_people(list_dic1, list_dic2)
print("2 -", [{dict1['title']:dict1['people']} for dict1 in list_dic1])
```

output:

```
1 - [{'Castle in the Sky': ['https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/']}, {'Amaterasu': ['https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/']}]
2 - [{'Castle in the Sky': ['Pazu', 'Dola']}, {'Amaterasu': ['Dola']}]
```

Second question:

In what environment are u working? does it have data stored for each user?
let's say you have a global variable for each user of the website called `last_date` initialized to 1/1/2000.
In each time the method make_get_request you should check whether
`(datetime.now() - last_date).seconds < 60` and return from the function in that case, otherwise make the rest of it and save the new time to `last_date`.
For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_time_for_current_user(user_session_id=''):
    file_name = 'date_time' + str(user_session_id) + '.txt'
    try:
        with open(file_name, 'r+') as date_time_file:
            date_time_text = date_time_file.read()
            if date_time_text == '':
                return datetime.fromisoformat('2000-01-01T01:01:01.000000')
            return datetime.fromisoformat(date_time_text)
    except IOError:
        print("couldn't open the file", file_name)


def set_time_for_current_user(user_session_id=''):
    file_name = 'date_time' + str(user_session_id) + '.txt'
    try:
        with open(file_name, 'w+') as date_time_file:
            date_time_text = datetime.now().isoformat()
            date_time_file.write(date_time_text)
    except IOError:
        print("couldn't open the file", file_name)

    
def make_get_request(URL):
    current_time = datetime.now()
    last_time = get_time_for_current_user()
    if (current_time - last_time).seconds < 60:
        return None
    set_time_for_current_user()
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.json()
```

If the file is saved on the server, this code will make a delay for all users.
In that case, you should change the functions `get_time_for_current_user(...)` and `set_time_for_current_user(...)` to modify the relevant data.

anyway, in that scenario I would suggest you will work with async functions on the client-side and multithreading in the python - that way the user and the server won't get stuck until the API response.

Comment: You omitted the return statement in the first answer. As for the second question, I don't have to store the information for each user, I'm returning the information as plaintext. Thank you.

Comment: For the first answer - no. I did not omit the 'return' statement, it is not needed here.
The function replaces the values inside the dictionary, therefore it doesn't need to return anything. for your convenience, I will add an example of usage.

For the second answer - That was clear from the beginning.
The information I said you should store for each user is only the time of his last request from the API.
With my code - after 1 user sends a request from the API - all other users are blocked for 1 minute - you should change it depends on the server-side language you are using.

Comment: This is how I finally implemented the second question
 ```requests_cache.install_cache(cache_name='my_cache', backend='sqlite', expire_after=60)```

Comment: that is fine for browsers that support cache. But it may be annoying to develop with it cuz u might not see changes after writing them.
Anyway, by this method you do store data for each user, you just store it on their browser, you may consider storing only the time of last API usage, so you won't make the user save too much data.

If you find any of those comments helpful you may upvote if you feel like it.

Answer (score 1):

For what concern the list of dictionaries this will update list_dic1 with the new names:

```
[list_dic1[m]['people'].append(list_dic2[p]['name']) \
 for m in range(len(list_dic1)) \
 for p in range(len(list_dic2)) \
 if list_dic1[m]['title'] in list_dic2[p]['movies']]
```

Comment: Any help as regards the second question??

Comment: Actually, I didn't understand your problem. Right now, how often do you call the make_get_request? If you want to have an information that is not older than one minute can't you store the time information when you perform the get requests? Something like: if datetime.now()-time_of_request > 60s then perform get otherwise keep old responses.

Comment: Instead, if the problem is that your information is too old and store information for all people all the time is time consuming i think you should store some parameters for each person. For example store in the dictionary how many movies there are in their movie list and perform  the update only if the number of movies is higher than before

Comment: I am thinking of implementing a cache instead